# cython fast access to dictionary

Tags: dictionary, cython

I'm working on cython and in my program I have a lot of dictionary and I want to treat them by using cython optimization.

I saw on a [blog cython_for_high_and_low](https://smerity.com/articles/2018/cython_for_high_and_low.html) that the access of dictionary could be optimize

I want to do something like that:

```
%load_ext Cython

%%cython
cimport cython

dict_ = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}

cpdef sum_(unsigned char *data):
    cdef int total = 0
    cdef str i
    for i in data:
        total += data[i]
    return total

cdef:
    unsigned char *data = str(dict_).encode("utf-8")
sum_(data)
```

It's pretty linked to python function, maybe it's possible to optimize it in cython. I don't know how to access to the function because it's an unsigned char and we can't use python object.

Is there a way to access to dictionary faster than in a the python way ?

Maybe I'm proposing a method that it's not adapted, if you have any other option don't hesitate to propose it

Comment: `data` is a pointer into a temporary. I'm surprised it compiles, and even more surprised that it doesn't crash.

Comment: That crash because it's not the correct way to use it. My question is how to use this kind of script regarding the blog proposal